# Fill data in dropdown onclick table row (based on table row data) in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-directive

How can I write a function that takes data from a dropdown, and fills in the table row containing that dropdown?

HTML:

```
<table id="DataTable" border="1" ALIGN="center">
    <tr ALIGN="center">
        <th>name</th>
        <th>add</th>
        <th>number</th>
        <th>type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tcat" *ngFor="let item of Tdata">
        <td class="name">{{item.name}}</td>
        <td class="add">{{item.add}}</td>
        <td class="nyumber">{{item.number}}</td>
        <td class="type" ALIGN="center">
            <select *ngIf="dropData" (click)="jsFunction(item.number);">
                <option>--Select--</option>
                <option *ngFor="let currentData of dropData"> 
                    {{currentData.type}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

TS:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // called first api and filled the data
    this.Tdata=[
        { name: "xyz"
         add: "abc"
         number: 12345
         type: null },
        { name: "xyz1"
         add: "abc1"
         number: 78900
         type: null },
    ]
}

jsFunction(num){
    // calling the second API here based of the given parameter and that
    // is num.. for example I have clicked the dropdown on the first row
    // which has number=12345 so in dropdown, dropData will fill the
    // value type and that's not happening in my case

    this.dropData=[
        {number: "12345"
        type: "customer"},
        {number: "12345"
        type: "dealer"},
        {number: "12345"
        type: "client"},
        {number: "12345"
        type: "master"},
    ]
}
```

whats should happen here is on first API call I will fill the table note that the type is null and in Html there is dropdown so after I click on any dropdown so there I will call the second API and pass that clicked row number in it and after second API call that clicked dropdown should fill data which I get in response so that I can select one-off that data.
I have explained my situation. please ask me if you don't get the question. searched on google but couldn't find anything related to this. there must be something that I missed or I don't know about that
thank you so much.

Comment: In which part you are facing the issue

Comment: @AdritaSharma onclick dropdown the second API data is not filling in that particular row .

Comment: Show the response of the 2nd API call

Comment: @AdritaSharma  the second API response is the same as the dropData. and I want to bind all this.dropData.type in onclicked dropdown

Comment: I modified the demo, it is working. Data will be loaded only after you click on anything in the row

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Template:

Bind `(click)` event in `tr>`:

```
<tr class="tcat" *ngFor="let item of Tdata" (click)="jsFunction(item.number);">
</tr>
```

TS:

```
jsFunction(num){
   this.dropData= this.Tdata.filter(x => x.number == num)
}
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fm2zh1?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)